# How do I create indoor scene lighting?

Tags: unity, level-design

I'm building the inside of a space ship in Unity as POC. I need info on scene lighting.
Rooms, corridors or just in general how to make an enclosed scene look great with lights.

Keep in mind this is indoors and I can't really use the Directional Light and have to
rely on realistic light sources.

Thanks!

Comment: Your title and the body of your question are slightly different. The title asks for resources, but the body asks for the actual information. My recommendation: change the title to match the body, because requests for resources are generally inappropriate on this site.

Comment: Also, what is a POC?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are really asking but you have read the Unity documentation about lights and lightmapping, right?

Such as:
http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Components/class-Light.html
http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Manual/Lightmapping.html
http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Manual/LightmappingInDepth.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, most of the time indoor environments in games have lightmaps. The lighting of the scene is baked into textures applied to the scene, rather than expensive lighting calculations done on the fly: http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Manual/LightmappingInDepth.html

However, while lightmaps give very good results on static geometry like level walls, they are useless on dynamic geometry because they are pre-calculated. For maximum realism in lighting of dynamic objects, modern games are increasingly turning to a technique called deferred lighting, in which lighting and shading is a separate render pass from colors. It's only available in Unity Pro: http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Components/RenderTech-DeferredLighting.html

Comment: Note that this answer is slightly out of date by now. The information about lightmaps is still correct, but now all lighting features are available in Unity free, not only Pro.